# not getting the right output in simple code

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a small exercise that should print all the odd numbers when a button is clicked. An error is shown when you don't fill in a number etc. When I put a number between 0 - 50, I will get the error saying "Not a number". Can someone help me with this little problem?

I don't know if the problem is with my output box in html, my tags or if there is something wrong with the if/ else statement.

```
let inputGetal = document.getElementById("getalInput"); 
//inputNumber
let genereerButton = document.getElementById("genereerButton"); //generateButton
let outputVenster = document.getElementById("outputVenster");
//outputWindow

let getal = inputGetal.value;

let onevenGetallen = () => {
    if(typeof getal == "number" && (getal >= 0 || getal <= 50)) {`enter code here`
       for (let i = 1; i < getal; i + 2) {
           outputVenster.value += i + '<tab>';
       }
    } else {
        outputVenster.value += "Geen goed getal" //not the right number
    }
};

genereerButton.addEventListener("click", onevenGetallen);
```

I want to see all the odd numbers starting from 1 untill the input number has been reached.

Comment: `inputGetal.value` returns a string.

Comment: Is there a way that I can get an integer value into that variable? Casting the 'let' for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move to get the number from the input inside of the function, otherwise you get the original value, not the actual.

You need to convert the string to an integer number by using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) with a *`radix`* of `10`.

Take the check with a [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()), because both conditions have to be `true`.

Finally you need an [addition assignment `+=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment) in the *`final-expression`* part of the [`for` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

```js
let inputGetal = document.getElementById("getalInput"),
    genereerButton = document.getElementById("genereerButton"),
    outputVenster = document.getElementById("outputVenster"),
    onevenGetallen = () => {
        let getal = parseInt(inputGetal.value, 10); // get value, take integer number
        if (getal >= 0 && getal <= 50) {            // logical AND &&
            outputVenster.value = '';               // empty output
            for (let i = 1; i <= getal; i += 2) {   // comparison <=, addition assignment
               outputVenster.value += i + ' ';      // take space as separator
            }
        } else {
            outputVenster.value = "Geen goed getal";
        }
    };

genereerButton.addEventListener("click", onevenGetallen);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="getalInput"> <input type="text" id="outputVenster"> <button id="genereerButton">go</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped me a lot.